# Small grammar that doesn't work; what am I missing (antlr4)

Tags: antlr

I have the following grammar.  It's supposed to accept the string shown in the comments in the header.  It does not. I must be missing something fundamental.  Hints on how to debug this would also be appreciated.

```
/*
  Should accept:
    b
    a:b
    a:b^10
    b^10
  Should not accept:
    :b
    a:
    a:^10
*/
grammar test;

filter:
  boostedField EOF
  ;

boostedField
  : qualifiedField (CARET NUMBER)?
  ;

qualifiedField
  : (FIELDNAME COLON)? term
  ;

term
  : TERM 
  ;

FIELDNAME: (LETTER | UNDERSCORE) (ALPHANUM | UNDERSCORE)* ;
NUMBER : NUM_CHAR+ ('.' NUM_CHAR+)? ;
COLON : ':' ;
CARET : '^' ;
WS  : (' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r' | '\u3000') -> skip ;
UNDERSCORE: '_' ;

// a term may not have a colon or a caret (unless escaped)
TERM : TERM_START_CHAR TERM_CHAR*;
fragment TERM_START_CHAR
  : ~( ' '  | '\t' | '\n' | '\r' | '\u3000' | ':'  | '^'  ) ;  
fragment TERM_CHAR : (TERM_START_CHAR | ESCAPED_CHAR) ;
fragment ESCAPED_CHAR :  ( '\\' . ) ;
fragment NUM_CHAR: '0'..'9';
fragment LETTER: 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' ;
fragment ALPHANUM: LETTER | NUM_CHAR;
```

Comment: "it does not" isn't helpful. Do you get an error? Wrong parse tree?

Comment: You're right, that wasn't helpful.

Comment: You're right, that wasn't helpful.  This should help:
input = "b"
line 1:1 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting ':'

input = "a:b"
line 1:2 mismatched input 'b' expecting TERM

input = "b ^10"
line 1:2 mismatched input '^' expecting ':'

input = "a:b^10"
line 1:2 mismatched input 'b' expecting TERM

Comment: The other thing I figured out today is that if I remove the FIELDNAME definition and replace it in the parser with TERM (the FIELDNAME definition is a subset of the TERM definition), then it starts working.  I would have thought that the parser would have realized that a colon can only be preceded by a FIELDNAME and it wouldn't have mattered, but apparently there's something I'm missing